# Python - FedEx Rate Services API doesn't return any service on weekends

Tags: python, fedex

I'm working with FedEx Rate Services api to retrieve all available international shipping services from the US.

I noticed that when I call their API on weekend no services returned.
The actual delivery will not take place on weekend but I would like to be able to retrieve services rates even if the API is being called on weekend.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Hey, I am just curious if you still have those problems as I have something similar with a php library.